# Error ORA-04088 using triger before UPDATE

Tags: java, oracle, ora-04088

I ran into this error. I tried to explore other 04088 topics but I am still not able to fix it.

My trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TU_INTEGRATIONS"
  BEFORE UPDATE ON INTEGRATIONS
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  bckId     INT;
  SQLBody   VARCHAR2(500);
  tableName VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.BCK_ID <> :NEW.BCK_ID THEN
    DELETE INT_MODULES im
     WHERE im.INT_ID = :NEW.INT_ID
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM (SELECT BCKM_ID
                                 FROM BACKENDS
                                WHERE BACKENDS.BCK_ID = :NEW.BCK_ID) b
                         JOIN ROUTING_SEQUENCES rs
                           ON rs.BCKM_ID = b.BCKM_ID);
  END IF;

  FOR item IN (
               SELECT MOD_TABLE
                 FROM MODULES m
                WHERE MOD_LEV_INTEGRATION = 1
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM INT_MODULES imi
                        WHERE imi.INT_ID = :NEW.INT_ID
                          AND imi.MOD_ID = m.MOD_ID)
               ) 
  LOOP
    SQLBody := 'DELETE ' || item.MOD_TABLE || ' WHERE INT_ID = ' ||TO_CHAR(:NEW.INT_ID);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLBody;  
  END LOOP;
END "TU_INTEGRATIONS";
```

Tables used:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The error is:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "INT_ID": invalid identifier ORA-06512: at "TU_INTEGRATIONS",
> line 21 ORA-06512: at "TU_INTEGRATIONS", 
> line 21 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TU_INTEGRATIONS'
> ```

I call merge method from entityManager on Integration object where I change just the INT_NAME column.

```
@Override
    public void createOrUpdate(T entity) {
        if (entity instanceof TimeTracked) {
            processAuditable((TimeTracked) entity);
        }
        T savedEntity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        entity.setId(savedEntity.getId());
    }
```

Thank you for your tips!

Comment: Please don't post the table descriptions as images; instead, post them as `CREATE TABLE` statements as formatted text that we can copy/paste as it makes it much easier to debug if we can easily re-create the problem.

Comment: What are the table names stored in `modules.mod_table`, and do all of those tables have an `int_id` column? The error suggests not - it's coming from the `execute immediate` call. (For a trigger, the line number in a PL/SQL error starts from the PL/SQL trigger body - so here `DECLARE` is line 1, not line 4 - which can be confusing.) If you add `dbms_output.put_line(SQLBody);` before that, and run your merge from a client that can show the output, you can see which table it's actually erroring on.

Comment: _"DELETE INT_MODULES im"_, I think the 'FROM' keyword missing.  That is why it's not recognize "INT_ID" and shows the invalid identifier error.

Comment: @Sujay - the `FROM` isn't required - it's shown as an optional branch on [the syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DELETE.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't (directly) in the trigger code you posted; it's a run-time error that is coming from the dynamic SQL statement you are executing on line 21, which is where the error is reported (counting from the start of the PL/SQL trigger body, where `DECLARE` is line 1).

The issue is that your `modules` table has a row that is being included in the cursor query, but which has a `mod_table` value that refers to a table which does not have an `int_id` column.

To demonstrate if you have a row with `mod_table` set to `'TABLE_A'` and that table is defined as:

```
create table table_a (int_id number);
```

then your code doesn't error; but if you change it to:

```
create table table_a (dummy number);
```

then it throws exactly the error you see.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/umn6L1_8)

You either need to exclude tables which don't have that column form the query, or test for them before executing the delete. (Or revisit your logic...)